# Cannot access headless PI via SSH after upgrading from Buster to Bullseye

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian

Yesterday I upgraded my PI from headless Buster to headless Bullseye. I can ping my PI, but SSH no longer works. The connection is refused.

I tried to fix this problem by adding an ssh file on the boot drive. Unfortunately, ssh is not activated. The ssh file is not deleted.

Does anyone have any idea how I can solve this problem? Can I connect an external monitor to a headless installation to change the raspi-config directly on the device? A fresh installation is unfortunately not an option.